# Prototype Pollution in async linters error

Tags: webpack, linter

[linters error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v8gg.png)

```
npm audit report

async  <2.6.4
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution in async - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-fwr7-v2mv-hh25
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/jake/node_modules/async
  jake  >=8.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of async
  node_modules/jake
    ejs  >=3.1.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jake
    node_modules/ejs
      @hint/formatter-html  >=4.2.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of ejs
      node_modules/@hint/formatter-html
        @hint/configuration-accessibility  >=2.0.5
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @hint/formatter-html
        node_modules/@hint/configuration-accessibility
        @hint/configuration-development  >=8.0.5
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @hint/formatter-html
        node_modules/@hint/configuration-development
        @hint/configuration-progressive-web-apps  >=7.0.5
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @hint/formatter-html
        node_modules/@hint/configuration-progressive-web-apps
        @hint/configuration-web-recommended  >=8.0.5
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @hint/formatter-html
        node_modules/@hint/configuration-web-recommended

8 high severity vulnerabilities
```

even when I try to install jest I get the same error as well while deploying. I think  because of dependencies and node_modules it gives error but I don't know the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I got solved this issue, but it is wired, and I am confused because I did nothing reinstalled after 7 seven hours. and I got solved.